# Make my own template in MikTeX in Windows 10

Tags: miktex, templates, windows

I realize this has probably been asked before but I couldn't find it. I'm trying to save a .tex document as a template inside my computer, but I don't know where to save it. I can do to \AppData and then I can find the \MikTeX folder, but I don't know where to specifically insert my file inside the MikTeX folder.

When creating a new folder from a template I can see MikTeX has templates called "article.tex", "KOMA-letter.tex" and so on, but I can't find these in my file explorer. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Welcome! I think this depends on the editor you're using, rather than the distribution.

Comment: I'm using texworks

Comment: Then I'd suggest editing your question to make that clear and tagging it `texworks`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on the editor.

- *TeXworks* under Windows: `C:\Users\YOURNAME\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\TeXworks\0.6\templates`. You find the default templates and can add your own. Use subdirectories for structure.
- *TeXnicCenter*: Have a look at the menu: "Extras - Options : Directories". You find the path of the default directory and can add more directories with your own files. Use subdirectories for structure.

Comment: wow, this works, thanks!